# Why can't I console.log the Facebook accessToken after login and redirect to an URL after?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a page where I have a button that triggers the FB.login function and I'm trying to console.log the accessToken after the response status is 'connected' and I also want to redirect to a page as a test with `window.location.href` but neither work.

When I login a popup window comes up and after successful login that popup window closes and I'm still on the initial page with the login button but nothing seems to happen with any code that I place inside my if statement. The facebook documentation is pretty vague and it doesn't have good examples on what I need to do after login.

```
function fb_login() {

        FB.login(function(response){
             

            if(response.status === 'connected'){
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                console.log(accessToken)
        
                 window.location.href = "https://google.com";
        
            }
        
        });

    }
```

This is the html button:

```
<div data-scope="public_profile,email,pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list" class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

Comment: if nothing is happening inside the `if` statement, perhaps `response.status !== 'connected'` - try `console.log(response.status)` **before** the `if`

Comment: nothing gets logged even before the if statement.

Comment: what about a console.log before `FB.login` ?

Comment: I get response is undefined

Comment: well, yes, I didn't say `console.log(response)` since that will stop your code from running. So `fb_login()` is executing, and `FB.login()` is executing since you're getting the popup ... but nothing in the callback - very odd. Is there anything else output in the console that may be of use for debugging?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help. Answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I misunderstood the flow. The fix was to remove the fb_login function since the button was already triggering the popup to login. I then added `data-onlogin="loginStatus()"` to the html button to trigger `FB.getLoginStatus` and from there I can now access the token on the page and send to a server if needed.

```
<div data-onlogin="loginStatus()" data-scope="public_profile,email,pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list" class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

```
function loginStatus(){
    
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // The user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire.
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        console.log(accessToken)
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // The user hasn't authorized your application.  They
        // must click the Login button, or you must call FB.login
        // in response to a user gesture, to launch a login dialog.
        } else {
        // The user isn't logged in to Facebook. You can launch a
        // login dialog with a user gesture, but the user may have
        // to log in to Facebook before authorizing your application.
        }
        });     

    }
```